# how to redirect to external website after successful ajax request data

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I working on this code...

```
<script>
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/>");
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM

      $('#simple-post').click(function(){
 $('#simple-msg').css({
     'display':'block',
   'background-color':'red',    
   'font-size':'44px'
 });
```

});

if the data that return is successful it appear like this :

```
{
status: "Success",
msg: "You have been registered"
}
```

and if the data that return is success but registration failed.

```
{
status: "Fail",
msg: "Please provide full name"
}
```

how do i redirect user to external website let say www.google.com if only the return status is success in the json ?

## =========================================

lol seem to answering my own question....

here how i manage to do it eventually ..

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            var a = JSON.parse(data)

            if(a.status == 'success') window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            else
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code     class="prettyprint">'+a.status+'</code></pre>');


        },
```

Comment: Redirecting in plain javascript is as simple as 

`window.location = "http://www.facebook.com"`

I don't know about jquery though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data.msg+'</code></pre>'); //if You want show only the message

if(data.status.toLowerCase == "success"){
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: If return type is json or not

Answer (score 0):

After the line of code,

```
$("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
```

Use the following Javascript code to redirect:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

[Why is window.location.replace() better than window.location.href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In your success block add window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {

            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';  // It redirect to google 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the success callback code like below,

you need to use window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";

```
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
 $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/>");
 var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 $.ajax(
 {
     url : formURL,
     type: "POST",
     data : postData,
     success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
     {
        if(data.status=="success"){
          window.location.href="http://www.google.com"; 
        }

         $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
     {
         $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
     }
 });
 e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM

   $('#simple-post').click(function(){
$('#simple-msg').css({
  'display':'block',
  'background-color':'red',    
  'font-size':'44px'
 });
```